# what is the need & use of apache felix web console bundle in liferay 7.1

Tags: apache-felix, liferay-7

I am new in liferay want to perform crud operation using service builder so i want to understand need  & use of apache felix web console bundle in liferay 7.1 so that i use it in order to check json/webservice api.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you are not looking at the right tool for the job.

The console enables you to interact with the OSGi framework, a good place to start is not on the console but on the file systems if you are looking into understanding how Liferay uses the framework. The framework is embedded into the web app in order to provide the environment where bundles can live and provide services collectively.

Gogo is an auxiliary tool that enables interaction, you can query if bundles are installed, check the dependencies that you missed and who is providing a certain service or exposing a package.

Most of day-to-day of this kind of information you can also find in the app manager and/or logs.

About testing you api, I assume you are looking for seeing if it was installed and if it was resolved and activated. The app managers can provide the first clue for this, but gogo is an adequate tool as well, you will need to learn its commands and syntax. Do not worry they are trivial, you can find a description on the Apache's project page an on Liferay's dev guide.

Now, if you are looking to test the API for correctives or availability, using gogo will demand custom commands and lots of extra logic other tools provide for you.